# Brand image don't seem to be "responsive"

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm having a problem with the brand logo image. Even though it looks good on my computer, I use a background-color to check the hover and it seems to be quite off position. Check this out please. By the way, I'm new to web design, so you may see lots of mistakes in my code, hehe. 
pd: I uploaded the image to Imgur but I use it directly from a folder.

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #4bd434;
  border-color: #209c44;
}
.navbar li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #209c44;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: black; 
}

body {
    background-image: url("Imagenes/1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.jumbotron h1{
    text-align:center;
}

.map-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:40%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.map-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
#brand-image {
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: -24px;
}

#brand-image:hover {
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <title>Central de Reparaciones</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".\sheet.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" a href="./index.html">
        <img class="img-responsive" id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="http://s14.postimg.org/rqjmwt8r5/logo.png"/> 
      </a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">         
        <li><a href="./ajax/heladeras.html">Heladeras</a></li>
        <li><a href="./ajax/lavarropas.html">Lavarropas</a></li>
        <li><a href="./ajax/secarropas.html">Secarropas</a></li>
        <li><a href="./ajax/microondas.html">Microondas</a></li>
        <li><a href="./ajax/televisores.html">Televisores</a></li>  
        <li><a href="./ajax/lavavajillas.html">Lavavajillas</a></li>           
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> (0223) 482-5446</a></li>
        <li><a href="./ajax/donde.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Dónde estamos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
    
  <div class="container">    
    <div class="jumbotron well">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Central de Reparaciones</h1>      
      </div>
      <p>Somos service oficial de Whirpool blablablablal</p> 
      <p>ASDSDASDSDASDDSDASDSDASDDSDDDASDASD</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<script src=".\script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is way off because of `padding-bottom: 40px;` in `#brand-image`. Removing it should resolve problem. If you like to keep same pixel ratio, use `margin-bottom` instead of `padding-bottom`.

Your CSS should look like:

`#brand-image {
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: -24px;
}`

Comment: But my logo grows large. Is there a way to make it fit automatically in the navbar?

Comment: In `#brand-image` set height to 70px and comment/delete padding-bottom/margin-bottom property. I would also add bootstrap 'hidden-xs' class in:`<a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" a href="./index.html">
        <img class="img-responsive" id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="http://s14.postimg.org/rqjmwt8r5/logo.png"/> 
      </a>` to hide logo on extra small devices.